# Map Linear Coordinate Frame to Google Earth's Spherical Coordinate Frame

Tags: javascript, coordinates, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have two vectors of points that when scatter plotted give me the following path: (each color is just a different segment of the path - some segments are straight and some segments are constructed by taking a certain arc length of a circle of some radius)

[image: s]

I want to then grab these points and plot them on the surface of the earth using Google Earth's Javascript API as so:

```
// Create the placemark
var lineStringPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');

// Create the LineString; set it to extend down to the ground
// and set the altitude mode
var lineString = ge.createLineString('');

lineStringPlacemark.setGeometry(lineString);
lineString.setExtrude(true);
lineString.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

// Add LineString points
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt( 200,  300);
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt( 200.50505051, 300);

... all points ...

ge.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlacemark);
```

So I am essentially treating them as latitudes and longitudes - don't really mind where the path appears on the earth at this point. When I do that, I get a path that loops in on itself and I am assuming it is because the earth is spherical.

[image]

I thought Google earth handles any kind of projection of a line onto the surface of the earth! What kind of transformation can I do to prevent this/achieve the desired path? The original points are coming from a coordinate frame with x=[0,500] and y=[0,500] and I'm trying to get the points in that frame, to a latitude and longitude on the earth!

Comment: That rendering looks correct. What did you expect exactly? How do you want the result to look like? Try drawing what you want onto a spherical surface like a ping-pong ball and work out the angles of the different segments from there. Chances are, you're just drawing it too big on the globe. Simply scaling it down would probably produce results closer to what you're expecting. Remember, on a sphere parallel lines always intersect twice.

Comment: how can I perform that scaling? The original points are coming from a coordinate from x=[0,500] and y=[0,500] and I'm trying to get the points in that frame, to a latitude and longtiude

Comment: A first try would be halve all coordinate numbers. so x/2, y/2 mapped to latitude longitude. Then if that's too big try quartering it and if it's too small try multiplying by a number between 0.55 and 0.99. Experiment with the scaling factor until you get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that latitudes and longitudes are wrapped.

Latitudes are expressed as degrees north or south of the Equator (0 degrees). Values range from −90 degrees to 90 degrees.

Longitudes are the angular distance in degrees, relative to the Prime Meridian. Values west of the Meridian range from −180 to 0 degrees. Values east of the Meridian range from 0 to 180 degrees.

The problem you have is that values outside the given ranges [-90,90] and [-180.180] are wrapped. This means that a latitude of, for example +150, is actually drawn at -60. A longitude of +500 would be drawn at +140.

To keep the plot within the frame you must restrict your Latitudes to a range [-90, 90] (between the North and South poles), your longitude would need to be restricted to the same amounts, as you can only see half the earth at once, [-90, 90].

To achieve this simply divided all your angles by a value of `5.6` - this would keep your line within the frame as 500/5.6 = 89.28